# bad request:Volley 400

Tags: header, request, android-volley

i want to connect to server by REST but i have Volley 400 error;
i tried almost everything i could find but nothing;
i'll be grateful if help me!
here is my codes:

```
private void volleyCall(String phone, String token) {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = "http://1*4.***.**.1*1/login/register-phone";

    Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("phone", phone);
    jsonParams.put("admin_token", token);
    Log.i("log1", "Json:" + new JSONObject(jsonParams));

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new 
JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("log2", "Json" + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //   Handle Error
                    Log.i("log3", "Error: " + error
                            + "\nStatus Code " + 
error.networkResponse.statusCode
                            + "\nResponse Data " + 
error.networkResponse.data
                            + "\nCause " + error.getCause()
                            + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
             headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
             Log.i("log4",headers.toString());
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }


    };

    queue.add(postRequest);

}
```

someone told me  should remove this form header : (and i tried too, But same error!)

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Whats your parameters to this API? send us documentation

Comment: you can see the api from here: http://164.132.81.151/login/register-phone

Comment: Do u try to change the type of `phone` and `admin_token` to string? the server just accepts the strings.

Comment: I'm sending String , i'm not? should i change somewhere? I call Volley like this : volleyCall("000000","333333"); which first parameter is number and second is token as i defined .

Comment: Ok, just change `phone` and `admin_token ` to string and double check it, and u can check the server by postman it might be a server error.

Comment: what do you mean change phone to String? this is String now. what should i change?